# Colorbox popup: click on parent window without closing the colobox window

Tags: popup, parent, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to display the help of my webapp. It's nice but what I want now is to open the popup with the help, and that the user can follow a tutorial video and doing at thte same time in the app.

So the possibility to click in the parent window without closing the colorbox window. I don't want to do action from the colorbox to the parent window, but directly click in the parent window, while watching my vid in the colorbox window.

I'm not sure colorbox is the tool to use with for this behaviour, but want to ask before to switch to another one.

Thanks
Bastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `overlayClose` and `escKey` to false.
Then you have to remove the overlay div by css. Like the following.

```
#cbobOverlay {
    display: none;
}
```

So, to finish you probably have to add some button or link to trigger close when you want.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">Close</a>

jQuery('.close').click(function() {
    jQuery.colorbox.close();
});
```

Hope this help.

*Reference*:

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: Hi, with some late, thanks for your answer. I did it already and it works when working on a page with some ajax. But that's not really easy to work with the help window above the main window. I will try something else.